# Android + AM PM in a Time Object?

Tags: android

I'm setting a Time Object in Android.  How do I set the AM and PM value at creation without relying on 24 hour time?  For instance:

```
int hour = 7; // this returns 7am
//int hour = 19; this returns 7pm   
myTime.set(second, minute, hour, day, month, year);
Log.i("TIME", "My time is: " + myTime);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really clear what you're trying to do, but I suspect you want something like:

```
// Assume input of hour12 in range [1, 12] and isPM is a boolean
int hour24 = (hour12 % 12) + isPM ? 12 : 0;
```

That's assuming you want an hour of "12" and "AM" to mean midnight.

Then use `hour24` when setting `myTime`.

Comment: @worked: It helps that I used pretty much exactly the same code last night in Noda Time :)